# unable to disable button in android

Tags: java, android, button

I tried everything but unable to disable that save button. i wrote it at the end of my onCreate.
Actually i wanted if user edits some notes and selects category from spinner it will automatically get enabled and i achieved it.
 But i want that first when user is on this page button should be disabled. When user dose his work it will enable.
But how should i disable this save button.

Here is my OfflinePBDetails.java class

```
package passbookManager;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

import logs.TraceLog;
import mainApplication.*;

import forbes.mPassbook.R;
import databaseClasses.DBAccountStatement;
import databaseClasses.DBCategoryMaster;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Build;

public class OfflinePBDetails extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener
{
    TextView tvDate;
    TextView tvAmount;
    TextView tvBalance;
    TextView tvParticular;
    TextView tvTitleAmount;
    EditText etNotes;

    Spinner spinnerCategory;

    Button btnBack;
    Button btnSave;

    String file_Path;
    Properties properties_config;

    long sessionTimeout;

    String passTransId;
    String passDate;
    String passParticular;
    String passDebitCreditIndicator;
    String passAmount;   
    String passTransString;
    String passBalance;
    String passFlag;

    String transId;
    String notes;

    int countDBRows;
    int countDBColumns;

    String dbSubCategory;
    String dbNotes;

    String selectedCategory;
    String[][] tableCategory ;
    ArrayList<String> categoryIncome;
    ArrayList<String> categoryExpense;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSelect;

    DBCategoryMaster dbCMaster;
    DBAccountStatement dbStatement;


        TraceLog tc = new TraceLog();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActionBar bar=getActionBar();
        bar.hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_offline_pbdetails);

        dbCMaster = new DBCategoryMaster(this);
        dbStatement = new DBAccountStatement(this);

        file_Path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Android/data/forbes.mPassbook/"; 
        readConfigFileDetails();

        if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9)
        {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
        }

        try
        {

            tvDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_getDate);
            tvParticular = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_getParticular);
            tvAmount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_getAmount);
            tvTitleAmount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_titleAmount);
            tvBalance = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_getBalance);
            spinnerCategory = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spn_selectCategory);
            etNotes = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_getNotes);
            btnBack = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
            btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            passTransId = intent.getExtras().getString("TransactionId");
            passDate = intent.getExtras().getString("Date");
            passParticular = intent.getExtras().getString("Particular");

            passAmount = intent.getExtras().getString("Amount");
            passTransString = intent.getExtras().getString("TransString");
            passDebitCreditIndicator = intent.getExtras().getString("Indicator");
            passBalance = intent.getExtras().getString("Balance");
            passFlag = intent.getExtras().getString("FilterFlag");

            tvDate.setText(passDate);
            tvParticular.setText(passParticular);
            tvTitleAmount.setText(passTransString);

            if(tvTitleAmount.getText().equals("Withdrawal Amount"))
            {
                tvAmount.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
            else
            {
                tvAmount.setTextColor(Color.rgb(48,128,20));
            }

            String trimAmount = passAmount.trim();
            String trimBalance = passBalance.trim();
            tvAmount.setText(trimAmount);
            tvBalance.setText(trimBalance);

            etNotes.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
            {
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) 
                {
                    btnSave.setEnabled(true);
                    resetDisconnectTimer();
                    //                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "After Typing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) 
                {
                    //                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Before Typing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
                {
                    //                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Typing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            btnBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    if(passFlag.equalsIgnoreCase("OfflinePB"))
                    {
                        Intent i = new Intent(OfflinePBDetails.this,OfflinePB.class);
                        i.putExtra("filterFlag","notes");/**********Code to go back to DisplayFilter Page***************************/
                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }
                    else if(passFlag.equalsIgnoreCase("notes"))
                    {
                        Intent i = new Intent(OfflinePBDetails.this,DisplayFilters.class);
                        i.putExtra("filterFlag","notes"); 
                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();   
                    }
                    else if(passFlag.equalsIgnoreCase("transfer"))
                    {
                        Intent i = new Intent(OfflinePBDetails.this,DisplayFilters.class);
                        i.putExtra("filterFlag","transfer"); 
                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();   
                    }
                    else if(passFlag.equalsIgnoreCase("cheque"))
                    {
                        Intent i = new Intent(OfflinePBDetails.this,DisplayFilters.class);
                        i.putExtra("filterFlag","cheque"); 
                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            });

            btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    try
                    {
                        btnSave.setEnabled(false);
                        transId = passTransId;
                        notes = etNotes.getText().toString();
                        //                  if(spinnerCategory.length()==0)
                        //                  {                       
                        //                      spinnerCategory.setError("Please Enter mPIN        ");                      
                        //                      mPin.requestFocus();
                        //                  }
                        //                  else 
                        //                      if(notes.trim().length()==0)
                        //                  {
                        //                      etNotes.setError("Please Add Your Notes         ");  
                        //                      etNotes.setText(null);                  
                        //                      etNotes.requestFocus();
                        //                  }

                        if(dbStatement.updatePassbook(transId, selectedCategory, notes))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Updated Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            //                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "selectedCategory : " + selectedCategory, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            //                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "notes : " + notes, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }

                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        tc.WriteToTransactionLog("Exception: OfflinePBDetails.java Save.setOnClickListener():- "+e.toString());
                    }
                }
            });

            dbGetCategoryList();
            btnSave.setEnabled(false);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            tc.WriteToTransactionLog("Exception: OfflinePBDetails.java onCreate():- "+e.toString());
        }

    }

    public void dbGetCategoryList()
    {
        int element;

        try
        {

            Cursor rs = dbCMaster.getData();

            countDBRows = rs.getCount();
            countDBColumns = rs.getColumnCount();

            tableCategory = new String[countDBRows][countDBColumns];

            rs.moveToFirst();

            for(element = 0; element < countDBRows; element++)
            {       
                tableCategory[element][0] = rs.getString(0); // subCategory
                tableCategory[element][1] = rs.getString(1); // Category
                tableCategory[element][2] = rs.getString(2); // transType

                rs.moveToNext();

                //                      String finalData = tableCategory[element][0]+ " " + tableCategory[element][1]
                //                              + " " + tableCategory[element][2];
                //                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "finalData : " + finalData, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            rs.close();

            showCategoryList();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            tc.WriteToTransactionLog("Exception: OfflinePBDetails.java dbGetCategoryList():- "+e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void showCategoryList()
    {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        int element;
        String transType;

        categoryIncome = new ArrayList<String>();
        categoryExpense = new ArrayList<String>();
        //      categoryIncome = new String[2];
        //      categoryExpense = new String[3];

        try
        {

            for(element = 0; element < countDBRows; element++)
            {       

                transType = tableCategory[element][2];

                //              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "transType : " + transType, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "passDebitCreditIndicator : " + passDebitCreditIndicator, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if(passDebitCreditIndicator.equalsIgnoreCase("D"))
                {

                    if(passDebitCreditIndicator.equalsIgnoreCase(transType))
                    {
                        if(tableCategory[element][0].equalsIgnoreCase("Others-E"))
                        {
                            categoryExpense.add("Others");  
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            categoryExpense.add(tableCategory[element][0]);
                        }
                        //                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "categoryExpense : " + categoryExpense, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        i++;
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    if(passDebitCreditIndicator.equalsIgnoreCase(transType))
                    {
                        if(tableCategory[element][0].equalsIgnoreCase("Others-I"))
                        {
                            categoryIncome.add("Others");   
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            categoryIncome.add(tableCategory[element][0]);
                        }
                        //                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "categoryIncome : " + categoryIncome, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        j++;
                    }
                }
            }


            if(passDebitCreditIndicator.equalsIgnoreCase("D"))
            {
                adapterSelect = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_pb_details,categoryExpense);
                //              adapterSelect = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categoryExpense);
            }
            else
            {
                adapterSelect = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_pb_details,categoryIncome);
                //              adapterSelect = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categoryIncome);
            }

            adapterSelect.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            spinnerCategory.setAdapter(adapterSelect);

            spinnerCategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

            checkDBData();

            if(dbSubCategory.equalsIgnoreCase("Others-E") || dbSubCategory.equalsIgnoreCase("Others-I"))
            {
                dbSubCategory = "Others";   
            }

            ArrayAdapter myAdap = (ArrayAdapter) spinnerCategory.getAdapter(); //cast to an ArrayAdapter
            int spinnerPosition = myAdap.getPosition(dbSubCategory);

            //set the default according to value
            spinnerCategory.setSelection(spinnerPosition);

            etNotes.setText(dbNotes);

            // to disable save button after notes is filled with note from db and item is selected from item listner
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            tc.WriteToTransactionLog("Exception: OfflinePBDetails.java showCategoryList():- "+e.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
    {
        //      try
        //      {
        spinnerCategory.setSelection(position);
        selectedCategory = (String) spinnerCategory.getSelectedItem();

        if(passDebitCreditIndicator.equalsIgnoreCase("D"))
        {

            if(selectedCategory.equalsIgnoreCase("Others"))
            {
                selectedCategory = "Others-E";  
            }
            //              else
            //              {
            //                  selectedCategory = selectedCategory;
            //              }
            //              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "selectedCategory : " + selectedCategory, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else
        {

            if(selectedCategory.equalsIgnoreCase("Others"))
            {
                selectedCategory = "Others-I";  
            }
            //              else
            //              {
            //                  selectedCategory = (String) spinnerCategory.getSelectedItem();
            //              }
            //          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "selectedCategory : " + selectedCategory, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        btnSave.setEnabled(true);



        //               switch (position) {
        //               case 0:
        //                   // Whatever you want to happen when the first item gets selected
        //                   break;
        //               case 1:
        //                   // Whatever you want to happen when the second item gets selected
        //                   break;
        //               case 2:
        //                   // Whatever you want to happen when the thrid item gets selected
        //                   break;}
        //      }
        //      catch(Exception e)
        //      {
        //          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception onItemSelected : " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //      }
    }

    public void checkDBData()
    {
        try
        {
            int element;        
            Cursor rs = dbStatement.getCategory(passTransId);

            //          int countCategoryRow = rs.getCount();
            //          int countCategoryColumn = rs.getColumnCount();

            rs.moveToFirst();

            dbSubCategory = rs.getString(13);
            dbNotes = rs.getString(14);

            rs.moveToNext();


            //          String reducedNotes = dbNotes.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
            ////            String str =dbNotes.substring(0, 3);
            //          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "reducedNotes : " + reducedNotes, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            tc.WriteToTransactionLog("Exception: OfflinePBDetails.java checkDBData():- "+e.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    public void readConfigFileDetails()
    {
        try
        {
            properties_config= new Properties();
            FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream(file_Path + "config.properties");
            properties_config.load(fis2);

            sessionTimeout = Long.parseLong(properties_config.getProperty("session_timeout"));

            fis2.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            tc.WriteToTransactionLog("Exception: OfflinePBDetails.java readConfigFileDetails():- "+e.toString());
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
    {
        if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) 
        {
            onBackPressed();
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() 
    {
        return;
    }


    public void onRestart() 
    {
        finish();
        super.onRestart();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Welcome.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
        finish();
    }


    private Handler disconnectHandler = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
        {

        }
    };

    private Runnable disconnectCallback = new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Session Expired", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println("Session Expired");

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Welcome.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    };

    public void resetDisconnectTimer()
    {
        disconnectHandler.removeCallbacks(disconnectCallback);
        disconnectHandler.postDelayed(disconnectCallback, sessionTimeout);
    }

    public void stopDisconnectTimer()
    {
        disconnectHandler.removeCallbacks(disconnectCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUserInteraction()
    {
        resetDisconnectTimer();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() 
    {
        super.onResume();
        resetDisconnectTimer();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() 
    {
        super.onStop();
        stopDisconnectTimer();
    }
}
```

Here is my .xml file :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bbk_base_all"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:paddingRight="3dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtwelcome" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonborder"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_titleDate"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                android:text="Transaction Date"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_getDate"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                android:text="Date"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonborder"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_titleParticulars"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                android:text="Particulars"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_getParticular"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="50"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:maxLines="4"
                android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                android:text="Particulars"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonborder"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_titleAmount"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                android:text="Amount"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_getAmount"
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                android:text="Amount"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonborder"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_titleBalance"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                android:text="Balance Amount"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_getBalance"
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                android:text="Balance"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonborder"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_titleCategory"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                android:text="Select Category"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spn_selectCategory"
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonborder"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_titleNotes"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                android:text="Notes"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_getNotes"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout1"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
                android:hint="Add Your Own Notes"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
            </EditText>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Transaction Details"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/normalbuttonborder"
        android:text="Save"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:enabled="false" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:background="@drawable/normalbuttonborder"
        android:text="Back"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initially disable that `Button` after `findViewById` like this

```
btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
btnSave.setEnabled(false);
```

The problem is you have `Spinner` where u enabling that `Button`. By default **1st item of Spinner is selected automatically and it is call in onCreate(...)** and your `Button` gets enabled what you can do

Change logic of enabling that `Button` in `Spinner's OnItemSelected(...)` check if previously selected value and currently selected value is equal and `EditText's` value has not been changed then disable that `Button` otherwise enable that `Button`. Use `boolean` flag for this work.

Comment: i tried it but its not working because what i am doing is in onCreate fetching values from database and setting it in Notes EditText.
So afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) methods is gets called while setting values from database. Then button gets enable.
But i Want to disable that save button when that activity is launched.

Comment: this will surely disable that `Button` but the problem is u have `Spinner` where u enabling that button. Bydefault **1st item of `Spinner` is selected automatically** and ur btn get enabled what u can do **create custom spinner** for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

You didnt disable your button before enabling it.

disble your button after declaring it.

```
btnSave.setEnabled(false);
```

Then enable it in your textChanged method

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to disable your button use:

```
btnSave.setEnabled(false);
```

or try setting:

```
btnSave.setClickable(false);
```

along with setEnabled(false)

Alternatively, use below line in your xml:

```
android:clickable = "false"
android:enabled = "false"
```

and whenever user is done with note editing (i.e after selecting spinner item ) enable both(enabled & clickable) on btnSave according to your logic i.e use:

```
btnSave.setClickable(true); 
btnSave.setEnabled(true);
```